# Best way to get user id for get_users function?

Tags: users

I'm trying to make a table of users by role type. What is the best-practices method of getting the user id? My goal is to print each users first & last names, username and email.

What I have now:

```
$get_admins = array(
    'blog_id' => $GLOBALS['blog_id'],
    'role' => 'administrator',
);

$blogusers = get_users($get_admins);
foreach ($blogusers as $user) { 
$userid = get_userdata($bloguser->user_id);
$user_info = get_userdata($userid);

    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'. $user_info->user_firstname .'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $user_info->last_name .'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $user->user_login .'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $user->user_email .'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

note: In my example above getting the user id does not work.

Codex reference: [get_users()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you're using `$bloguser` instead of `$user`.

And there's no point in calling get_userdata() since get_users() already returns user objects:

```
foreach ($blogusers as $user) {
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'. $user->first_name .'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $user->last_name .'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $user->user_login .'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $user->user_email .'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Dropping the redundant code works for stuff stored in the `wp_users` table. First/last name though is meta and stored in `wp_usermeta`. [I'm sure you already know this :)] So using `$user->user_firstname` isn't putting out anything. What am I not understanding? Thanks @Scribu

Comment: `get_users` performs a join to the meta table, and the fields param defaults to `all` so that meta data should come back in the query(unless a given value isn't currently set for the given user(s)). Verify the users you're not seeing a first name for definately have one set.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because in `foreach` loop  `get_userdata($bloguser->user_id);` line, `$bloguser` is an unknown object variable. Please try this code:

```
$get_admins = array(
    'role'    => 'admin',
    'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
);
$blogusers  = get_users( $get_admins );
echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
    echo '<li>' . $user->first_name . '</li>';
    echo '<li>' . $user->last_name  . '</li>';
    echo '<li>' . $user->user_login . '</li>';
    echo '<li>' . $user->user_email . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```